# YouTube API to get the most recent videos (with share URL) from a given channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

can some help me in drafting the right API call to get the most recent video form channel with shared URL (URL which i can embed in my web site)

[image]

I was able to get the title and description using the YouTube API version 3.  But i am not able to get the "**share this video** URL".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is not what you want, I apologize.

If you are asking what I think you are asking. I would just go to the next tab to the right ("Embed").  There is box there with the full embed code for your website.  You can either use that code or copy the url out of it.

Just to save you some trouble, here is the code for that particluar video:

```
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/HhHhacseGw0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the url:

```
    http://www.youtube.com/embed/HhHhacseGw0
```

If that is not what you are looking for, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I am looking for a API directly to call from my website.  I am processing the API from my end to get the following fields   1. Title  2. Description 3. share this video (URL)

Comment: how can i get the above URL you stated from the API.  Can you please, send me the API endpoint you used to generate this response

Comment: Are you asking how I came up with that code and url?